# Angular Validation: Access a Form from another Form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have these two simple forms -

```
<form novalidate name="frm1" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="sectionTxt" class="control-label col-sm-2">Section(s)</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2" ng-class="{ 'has-error':lq.section.$error.pattern}">
            <input type="text" id="sectionTxt" name="section" ng-model="query.section" class=" col-sm-2 form-control" ng-pattern="/^(\d)+$/" />
        </div>
        <div style="color:red" ng-show="form1.section.$error.pattern">Numbers Only Please</div>
</fieldset>
</form>

<form novalidate name="frm2" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group row">
        <button class="col-sm-1 col-sm-push-8 btn btn-default" type="submit" ng-click="filterGrid()" ng-disabled="!frm1.$error">Search</button>
    </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Form1 is always null or falsy in form2.

How do I access form1 from form2 in the ng-disabled directive? I need to inspect whether or not form1 is valid before enabling the submit button in form2.

I'd also prefer to do the validation completely in the markup and not write any JS code in the controller or directives.

Comment: Your logic seems to be "disable this button if there are not errors", is that what you want?

Comment: You already accessed it. Data is shared within one controlled, within one $scope. As I remember you are free to use that frm2.$valid anywhere in same template

Comment: If they are so related, why not put them in the same form?

Comment: All I'm trying to do is access form 1 from form 2. This syntax in form 2 does not work - form2.$error always return false. ng-disabled="!form1" button is disabled, ng-disabled="form1" button is enabled. So obviously form 2 is seeing form 1. How do I reference another form in themarjup? Is this even possible?